# how to update process bar in c# in another thread which are execute in another class

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, progress-bar

i am working on windows form
i want update progress bar from another thread 
this thread execute code of another class
like:

```
 class form1
  {
         //start thread in this class
        //which are execute second class method
  }
  class second
  {
     //in this class i want to update progress bar
   }
```

exactly i'm working with files and read files in "second class" one by one if processing on one file is completed then i want to update process bar (this whole process run in another thread not ui thread) . how can i do this.
thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to do the invoking yourself, you could do something like this:

```
//This goes in your Form1
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(WorkThread);
        t.Start();
    }

    private void WorkThread()
    {
        DoSomeWork w = new DoSomeWork();

        w.Work();

        while (w.progress < 100)
        {
            UpdateFromThread(w.progress);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateFromThread(int progress)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            MethodInvoker MyDelegate = delegate { UpdateFromThread(progress); };
            this.Invoke(MyDelegate);
        }
        else
        {
            progressBar1.Value = progress;
        }
    }

//Class to do some work.
class DoSomeWork
{

    public int progress { get; set; }

    public DoSomeWork()
    {
        progress = 0;
    }

    public void Work()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(WorkThread);
        t.Start();
    }

    private void WorkThread()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            progress += 1;
            Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
    }
}
```

You didn't give any specifics as far as what you were trying to do exactly, but this is the general idea. BackgroundWorkers are definitely cleaner.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a second thread just to update the progress periodically.  If it's really necessary to throttle the progress updates (usually it's not) then at the very least you should be using a timer.

Comment: two things i want to ask you first why you add another thread it's not possible in same thread? and when i close my form i get this exception "Cannot access a disposed object."

Comment: in this line   "this.Invoke(MyDelegate);"

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use a `BackgroundWorker` object.  There's a complete code example for how to use one [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Failing that, you need to use [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to update the progress bar in the other class.  This will alleviate the cross-thread errors that you're probably getting.

Comment: i try both method but but BackgroundWorker object is not working in another class and invoke and begininvoke give this exception  " Invoke   or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created".

Comment: Why are you trying to update a progress bar in a form that hasn't been instantiated yet?

Comment: i show you some demo code           private  void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // await Task.Run(() => cnt());
            second a = new second();
            ThreadStart theprogress = new ThreadStart(a.cnt);
            Thread startprogress = new Thread(theprogress);
            startprogress.Name = "Update ProgressBar";
            startprogress.Start();

        }   public void UpdateProgress()

        {
            progressBar1.Value += 1;

        }

Comment: class second
    {

        public void cnt()
        {
            Form1 af = new Form1();
            updatebar ast = new updatebar(af.UpdateProgress);
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                if (i % 10 == 0)
                {
                    af.progressBar1.Invoke(ast);

                }
                if (i == 100)
                {
                    break;
                }
                i++;
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }

Comment: Please don't put code in comments.  As you can see, it's impossible to read.  Edit your question instead.

Comment: please help me  to understand what's i'm doing wrong